# How to fix the error when rgb2gray function in gui is used?

Tags: matlab-guide

I'm writing the following matlab  code to display 16bit tiff image in the axes using my GUI:

```
 I1 = gpuArray(reshape(linspace(0,1,20),[5 4])); %performs the conversion on a GPU.
W = gather (I1);
[I1,map] = imread(fullname);
imshow(I1,map)
myImageAsGray = rgb2gray(map)
%graycomatrix ignores pixel pairs if either of the pixels contains a NaN,
%replaces positive Infs with the value NumLevels,
%replaces negative Infs with the value 1. 
%ignores border pixels, if the corresponding neighbor pixel falls outside the image boundaries
graycomatrix(I1, 'offset', [0 1], 'Symmetric', true)
graycomatrix(I1, 'offset', [0 1], 'Symmetric', false) 
graycomatrix(I1, 'offset', [0 -1], 'Symmetric', false)
imshow(myImageAsGray)
imagesc(myImageAsGray)
```

I'm able to open and to display the image (I also tried to use ind2rgb) but an error message is reported:

```
:
Error using rgb2gray>parse_inputs (line 81)
MAP must be a m x 3 array.
Error in rgb2gray (line 35)
X = parse_inputs(varargin{:});
Error in que (line 9)
I = rgb2gray(old_image);
```

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Do you see this for all images you feed to this?

Comment: Yes, I tried with different images and the problem is the same.

Comment: I also tried to check that my image is in grayscale but probably something is nont completely correct.